# Ranking text to see if they got a better health plan

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write code that will evaluate whether their plan change from the previous year and put "Moved Up" in a column to the right if the plan changed. First the code needs to make sure that they have the same member ID and that it is a new year. Here is what it looks like in excel:

```
 000880093121    2015     Bronze 60 HMO  
 000880093121    2016     Silver HMO
```

My first thought was to use nested IF statements but I do not know how to tell excel that the Silver plan is a better plan than Bronze. There is a total of five different plans that members can have.

```
=IF(A3=A2,IF(B3>B2,"Moved Up"))
```

This will successfully compare the member ids and make sure that it is a new year. I just do not understand how to give text values a numeric value so that it can be compared. Also there is over 30k rows that I will be applying it to.

The output that I am looking for should be this:

```
 000880093121    2015     Bronze 60 HMO     -
 000880093121    2016     Silver HMO        Moved Up
```

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I would use a VLOOKUP table, and rank the plan with an id number. Then you can lookup that id to still return the description, but use intelligent ids to rank the plans according to least to worst or from 1 to 5 etc..

Comment: I am not familiar with intelligent ids, could you possible give me an example?

Comment: All I meant was, if you want to rank your HMO plans in some way. So perhaps 1=Bronze, 2=Silver, 3=Gold etc. So that way you could sort on the number representing the description. This would simplify comparison of plans 1 relative to 2 etc, instead of text. Here's an example upgrading plans from Bronze-> Silver, Silver -> Gold https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRPEUth6XtLcMRYyY9CsyxMoX71hZ4zaLD06tvWZ88g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Put the different plans in a table sorted from "least-good" (top) to "best" (bottom), and name that range (e.g.) "planTable".

Then you can do this:

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3>B2),
    IF(MATCH(C3,plantable,0)>MATCH(C2,plantable,0),"Moved Up",""),
    "")
```

Comment: It just gives me the error of too many arguments for this function.

Comment: It fixed that problem of arguments but just gives #N/A a lot and never says moved up when the plan changed. Is there something I can clarify that could help? Also was the B2>B3 a mistake

Comment: Yes - should have been `B3>B2` based on your example. I did test before my last edit (though I had my dates sorted in the other direction)